# Change GameObject, when angle of a speedometer is changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car speedomeeter from 0-300 km/h. When I am at 80km/h i want to change a gameObject in the background of my speedometer. I have different angles (z-rotation) when the speed is changing. Is there any option to get access to the angle and enable new objects like:

```
if(angle > value) // enable a new object
```

I am a beginner and I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can simply add the gameObject in your scene in the right positions and disable then with the little **check** at the top of the inspector.

Inside the script, you can then call these objects:

    public GameObject number1;
    public GameObject number2;

And then drag the invisible objects from the **hierarchy** inside the cell of the script inside your object inspector.

Then you should put some ifs and set them active:

 

    if(angle < 20)
    { number1.setActive(true);
    number2.setActive(false);
    }
    else if(angle >20)
    { number1.setActive(true);
    number2.setActive(true);
    }

Remember that you can set the objects active in the **edit** view to be able to manage them and put in the `Start()` a simple line where you `.setActive(false)` so when you press play they start disabled
```

Comment: [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133552/357004)

Comment: I thought I could genuinely help him with this little problem, I have flagged the answer already. Is it not fair? @derHugo

Comment: As the answer in the link says `Generally speaking, answering questions that should get closed encourages bad behavior.` .. here the OP is basically asking for a ready solution without providing any own research/attempt to solve the "issue" or the code that was used. For me that's off-topic ;)

Comment: ok, my bad. I was just answering a confused beginner, but I see your point and SO view. But if the question will be closed, my answer also will lose reputation or will be deleted so it is not that bad I think, maybe, probably ;D @derHugo

Comment: Thanks @Leoverload ! I tried this before but i do not know how to get access to the angle... ? You know what I mean? Only "angle" did not work out because thats not the name of the z-rotation

Comment: Ahahah then just add the name of the z-rotation I did not know it :) @unitybeginner